# Sized Biased Picking Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I am having trouble understanding the following proof on sized biased picking. We have the following situation:

Let $ X_1, \cdots , X_n $ be i.i.d. and positive, and $S_i = X_1 + \cdots + X_i$ for $ 1 \leq i \leq n $. The values of $S_i/S_n$ are used to partition the interval $[0,1]$, each sub-interval has size $Y_i = X_i/S_n$. Suppose $U$ is an independent uniform r.v. on $(0,1)$, and let $\hat{Y}$ denote the length of the sub-interval containing $U$. We aim to calculate the distribution of $\hat{Y}$.

The claimed result is $ \mathbb{P}(\hat{Y} \in dy) = n y \, \mathbb{P}(Y \in dy) $, where the notation means $\mathbb{P}(\hat{Y} \in A) = \int_A n y \mu(y) \, dy$ with $\mu$ the law of $Y$ (I think perhaps they mean the density function $f_Y(y)$).

The proof given is 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\hat{Y} \in dy) &  = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left(\hat{Y} \in dy, \frac{S_{i-1}}{s_n} \leq U < \frac{S_i}{S_n}\right) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in dy, \frac{S_{i-1}}{S_n} \leq U < \frac{S_i}{S_n}\right) \\
&  =  \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X_i}{S_n} \, 1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in dy\right)\right] \tag{$\ast $} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n y \, \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_i}{X_n} \in dy \right) \tag{$\ast  \ast $} \\
& =ny \, \mathbb{P}(Y \in dy) \\
\end{align*}

I do not understand the equalities $(\ast)$ and $(\ast \ast)$, and do not fully understand the notation given in the proof.

Comment: I have the exact same question. I am not very familiar with manipulating those quantities that involve $dy$ (continuous probability distributions, in the measure theoretical sense). In the $(\ast)$ line, the lecturer said you "integrate out the $U$", which doesn't make sense to me. I am confused about what exactly are the rules of manipulating such expressions. For what it's worth, I do understand example 4.6 and 4.7 [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/notes-new.pdf). (This question comes from the section 4.3)

Comment: Example $4.6$: If $X\sim\text{Unif}[0,1]$ with law $\mu$ such that $\mu (dx) = 1 dx$, then the $X$-size biased distribution $\hat{X}$ has law $\hat{\mu}$ such that $\hat{\mu}(dx) = (E(X))^{-1}x \mu(dx) = 2x dx$. The factor x
biases towards larger values of X. Example $4.7$: If $X\sim \text{Expo}(\lambda)$ with law $\mu$ such that $\mu(dx) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$, then $\hat{X}$ has law $\hat{\mu}$ such that $\hat{\mu}(dx) = (E(X))^{-1} x \mu(dx) = \lambda \cdot x \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856400/finding-size-bias-distributions/1859858?noredirect=1#comment8417702_1859858

Comment: I can also understand Remark 4.12 [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/notes-new.pdf) perfectly, but I still do not understand this proof (the two starred lines).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the notation in the proof, but the result is quick with a continuous version of Bayes' rule. Let $A_i$ be the event that $U$ lands in the $i^{\text{th}}$ interval. By symmetry, the unconditional probabilities $\Pr[A_1], \dots, \Pr[A_n]$ are all $\frac1n$.

Then
$$
   f_{Y_i \mid A_i}(y) = \frac{\Pr[A_i \mid Y_i = y] f_{Y_i}(y)}{\Pr[A_i]} = \frac{y f_{Y_i}(y)}{1/n} = n y f_{Y_i}(y) = ny f_Y(y).
$$
The conditioned random variable $Y_i \mid A_i$ is not literally the same thing as $\hat Y$. However, by the law of total probability, we have $$f_{\hat Y}(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_{\hat Y \mid A_i} (y) \Pr[A_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n f_{Y_i \mid A_i}(y) \Pr[A_i].$$ This is just an average of $f_{Y_i \mid A_i}(y)$ over $i=1,\dots,n$, and since they're all $ny f_Y(y)$, we conclude that $f_{\hat Y}(y) = ny f_Y(y)$.

Moreover, the intuition for the result comes from Bayes' rule. We are saying that the distribution of the size of the picked interval is scaled up in proportion to the probability that an interval of that size would be picked (turning $f_Y(y)$ into $y f_Y(y)$). The constant factor of $n$ is just there to make the whole thing integrate to $1$ again.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a perfectly reasonable proof and I can follow it. However, I also would like an explanation on how the $P(\cdot \in dy)$ are manipulated, as in the question. This is because, later in the course, the lecturer seems to assume that the students are familiar with such manipulations. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Eh, that notation looks like quite a bit of a scam; I assume they wanted to write densities, since that probability is certainly $0$ for most continuous distributions. If you see a question like this, you should $100\%$ do it the way @Misha has done in their answer. If you want to manipulate densities properly, you will want to invoke Radon-Nikodym theorem at some point, but since all you want to know what those stars are, here is their semi-formal "justification":

For $(*)$, the informal justification is that the probability that $U$ is in the $i$th interval is $\frac{X_i}{S_n}$ so it comes out of that expectation because of independence of $U$. Semi-formally, we first rewrite:

\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in dy, \frac{S_{i-1}}{S_n} \leq U < \frac{S_i}{S_n}\right) \\
&\stackrel?= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon], \frac{S_{i-1}}{S_n} \leq U < \frac{S_i}{S_n}\right) \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon], \frac{S_{i-1}}{S_n} \leq U < \frac{S_i}{S_n}\right)\right] \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon]\right) 1\left(\frac{S_{i-1}}{S_n} \leq U < \frac{S_i}{S_n}\right)\right]\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon]\right) 1\left(\frac{S_{i-1}}{S_n} \leq U < \frac{S_i}{S_n}\right)\bigg|X, S\right]\right]\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon]\right) \mathbb{E}\left[ 1\left(\frac{S_{i-1}}{S_n} \leq U < \frac{S_i}{S_n}\right)\bigg|X, S\right]\right]\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon]\right) \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X_i}{S_n} \, 1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in dy\right)\right]
\end{align*}

Now, for $(**)$, informally, that indicator is only $1$ if that ratio is exactly $y$, so that random variable is either $y$ with probability equal to that ratio being equal to $y$, or $0$ otherwise. Semi-formally, we can write:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X_i}{S_n} \, 1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in dy\right)\right] &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon]\right) \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right]
\end{align*}

Note that

$$ 
\begin{align*}
&(y-\epsilon)\mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon]\right)\right] \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon]\right) \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right] \\
&\leq (y + \epsilon)\mathbb{E}\left[1\left(\frac{X_i}{S_n} \in [y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon]\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

and by plugging it into above and taking the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, you can show that that equality holds.

Comment: Thank you for your response . I have tried to come up with the same reasoning for (*) as well, but why can you assume the independence (after the 3rd equals sign)? Isn't the dependence of U and X_i kind of "the entire point" of size-biased picking (in the sense that U is more likely to fall in intervals where X_i is bigger)? I do hope you can clarify, thank you.

Comment: And, regarding your question about this notation, I think $P(Y \in dy)$ is the lecturer's notation for $\mu (dy)$, where $\mu$ is the law of $Y$. I've checked this across other derivations and it seems self-consistent. For example, if X is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, and we call its law $\mu$, then $\mu(dx) = \lambda e^{\lambda x} dx$, when we use it within an integral. Does this make sense? Thanks

Comment: U is an independent uniform random variable in your question (it says suppose that); very much independent from $X_i$s. Where $U$ lands with regards to $X_i$s of course is not independent. (The value of $U$ is independent of $X_i$s, which $X_i$s it is between is very much not). Also, yeah, I mean their notation kind of makes sense; you can then adapt this whole thing by adding a "dy" at the end of every line. Still kind of a scam though in my opinion :D. It is just significantly safer to work with what @Misha did.  Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for your edits @BenjaminWang!